# Allign two relative Layout

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

[image]How to align one relative layout to the middle of another relative layout. if both the Relative layout are siblings? 
I have tried multiple things but I couldn't find anything for this.
I need aligning the center of one fragment to the middle of another one and this second fragment can change size at runtime. as it has some switch to enable and disable some view.

F1 is always fixed and I need to change the position of the F2 so that it's center always align with the end of the F1 bottom

Comment: can you provide some sort of sketch for better understanding the problem?

Comment: can you post your tried xml?

Comment: @android_griezmann Please check if it my question is clear now

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/f1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/holder"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/holder"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"></RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/holder"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/f2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/holder"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"></RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note : Height & Width you can set it according to your requirements. To check your problem is solved or not, try to increase decrease height of the f2 layout.

Hope this works for you!!

Comment: in my problem, F1 is always fixed and I need to change the position of the F2 so that it's center always align with the end of the F1 bottom.